# Most in-demand items/skills in dystopian future

Tags: economy, dystopia

Civilization as we know it has fallen.  You want to begin to rebuild and/or set up a village shop to turn a quick buck.

What goods or services from the past (aka, now) would be most in demand?

Comment: in this same planet as ours? same ammount of population or a lot of people died?

Comment: Also define quick buck, everyhting that makes a lot of money requires either one  or all of the following : talent, time, sacrifice. I'd say the easiest way to make a quick buck is to scam others, but even that requires a lot of charisma

Comment: also how is the future? if there isn't much technology then an industrial fisherman who fishes in modern net boats isn't gonna be as valuable as the guy who regularly fishes with less technology and tools.

Comment: Hey Jimmy, welcome to world building. As of now it's not really possible to properly answer your question, because we lack information. How did civilization fall? Are basic resources for survival like clean water and food decently available? Is there any form of currency widely recognized, or any use for it (such as clean water being used as money)? Are there any dictatorial governments already formed regulating what you can or can't do/threatening your community? What are the main threats around your region? These factors can dramatically change demand for certain products.

Comment: Good questions!  Already that gives me a lot of leads I could chase.  I was thinking

Comment: Good questions!  Already that gives me a lot of leads I could chase.  I was thinking of something along the lines of the fall of the Roman Empire, where the great civilization of old is nearly forgotten and people are reduced to a subsistence farming lifestyle.  Like maybe somebody finds an iphone and is using it as a garden spade because they don't know what it is.  But then you show up with the knowledge of now, how do you use that to succeed personally and/or advance society?

Comment: Again, the environment and the conditions in which people are living in will play a big role in the demand. Sure knowing how to use the iPhone is neat, but if everyone is too busy trying to survive until the next day, the only ones that might be interested would be the members of the elite in already established communities, who do have the time and resources to worry about pastime activities.

Comment: What is the meaning of a "make a quick buck" if civilisation has fallen? Making quick bucks is not possible unless there is a functional and highly developed civilisation around. (For an easy to understand example, consider the early Middle Ages in north-western Europe: there is no way to make a quick buck, first because nobody has any bucks to give you, and second because everybody is busy surviving.) (Moreover, what services are available and desirable today and what services would be available and desirable if civilisation has fallen are two very different things.)

Comment: If civilization is fallen, paper money loses value. The value of currency is only as good as people's faith in the government. If government has fallen, it's down to a bartering economy. In such a world, the "richest" people are those who hold items that helps them survive. These people better have lots of guns and don't sleep to enforce honest trade or this anarchic world would just be full of looters and thieves. If they had the guns, they can be as much as a dick as they want. If they don't, those who try to profit in this world are the first to get killed and have their stuff taken.

Comment: @Jimmy, I would like to answer this, but as others have noted, we need more info. if you can start with explaining the remaining population size, method of the collapse and state of the infrastructure, I can arrange a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of skills and items that can be highly valuable, but that value is dependent on the settings of the new world; a world where all technology got destroyed by a solar flare would value older, more resistant, technologies and knowledge very highly (books, steam boilers or techniques to produce goods as an example).

But if the only thing lost was the societal structure (police, supply chains, etc) and not the technologies per se the most valuable items would be guns as mike has already answered, since everything else can be gradually reintroduced as long as you have the technologies and a way to secure yourself.

so let's focus on the loss of key resources kind and go from there.

In a fictional world where we lost the technologies that allowed our civilized world to exists there's a typical rollback to the last available era we can currently support, most likely early steam revolution era; that means we can have some production of goods but we'll still require a good amount of manual work to be done, specially on the food growing area, since most house farms can't really keep a normal family feed through the year.

this introduces a scenario that most fiction of the kind never considers: a lot of people who never even saw a farm shovel in real life is now is faced with "brutal" manual labor to simply survive.

On one side a lot of people underestimate the knowledge needed to make food grow (like the attempted farms on the CHAZ), so practical knowledge of how to make food would surely be worth enough to justify a lot of bucks or whatever your new society uses [image: the attempted farms on the capitol hill autonomous zone]

On the other side most people also underestimate how arduous is farm work when you're trying to grow enough food to feed a lot of people through the entire year, specially when instead of machines all you have is a lot of people who is not physically ready for this (and no, going to the gym a few hours in the week doesn't really prepare you for manual farm work, but you will fare a little better).

there would be a huge influx of broken bones, cuts, sore muscles and even some heart attacks, so medical knowledge would become really valuable, from how to fix a broken arm, up to how to make homemade aspirin from willow tree bark. so a simple stand who sells some sort of pain reliever or antibiotic would quickly rack up a small fortune

Hope this answer helps you or at least give you a new way to think about it

Answer (score 0):

## Guns, lots of guns.

Any skill makes its wielder a more valuable piece of property.  But in a fallen civilization, how many skills help the wielder to *own* things?  Power, deer meat, influence, truth, security, morality and all things grow from the barrel of a gun - a gun that shoots, that is.  That loony neighbor with the basement full of reloading supplies and tools, who not only makes his own black powder bombs but can cook up usable smokeless powder with cellulose and homemade nitric acid, who can repair and maintain what he has or build a fine improvised weapon complete with everything but a serial number ... well, if he didn't get hauled away by armed men before the Fall, he is going to have a lot of armed friends who stake their lives on his services afterward.  He may be only a shaman rather than a chief, but chiefs may have a short life expectancy... especially if he teaches his friends to shoot straight.